# google search results - append custom parameter to url string

Tags: search, google-search-appliance

how do you append an additional url parameter to a link in your google search results? is it possible to do this within the style sheet?

for example i have domain.com/result.htm - i want to change the link to domain.com/result.htm?param=1

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That´s quite simple.
On the default stylesheet find this code snippet:

```
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping='yes' select="U"/>
    </xsl:otherwise>
```

If you want to append a fixed param like in your example, changeit by:

```
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping='yes' select="U"/>
      <xsl:value-of select="'?extra=param'"/>
    </xsl:otherwise>
```

This will append to any url a "?extra=param"

HTH

Comment: thanks, i tried it but getting a error - "The reference to entity "testLink" must end with the ';' delimiter." any thoughts?

Comment: Hi, that´s because you entered an ampersand on the test url "&".
Try replacing it with "&amp;".
Just like:
<xsl:value-of select="'?extra=param&amp;param2=value2'"/>

Answer (score 0):

If google didn't crawl it like that, I don't think it's going to index it like that.